# Hive UDF Throws Class Not Found Exception in select

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm stuck in using UDF jar. I need to parse simple UserAgent in my UDF. I found a popular UserAgent parser http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils which I include in my project. In project I use maven. I added all dependencies, implemented eveyrthing and test it. It works fine in my local machine. Next I make clean install in maven for building jar. This jar I use in Hive via add jar {MyJarName} and then create a function: create temporary function {functionName} as {pathToUDFClass} and got exception like this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"bidid":"8326c0ec49e5746f1af03400f37e5797","tstamp":20131022185001163,"logtype":1
,"ipinyouid":"D89E8S5bwWz","useragent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)","ip":"61.138.253.*","regionid":374,"cityid":375,"adexchange":1
,"domain":"449a7568331085d43d5867de26ce1ee1","url":"5ecba5b62bafd3428cdc1398b40cf88f","anonymousurl":"null","adslotid":null,"adslotwidth":300,"adslotheight":250,"adslotvisibility":"Na","adslotformat":"Na","adslo
tfloorprice":0,"creativeid":"10722","biddingprice":294,"payingprice":135,"landingpageurl":"null","advertiserid":2821,"userprofileids":[10006,10110,10063]}                                                         
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:91)                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:68)                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:325)                                                                                                                  
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:150)                                                                                                        
        ... 14 more                                                                                                                                                                                                
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"bidid":"8326c0ec49e5746f1af03400f37e5797","tstamp":20131022185001163,"logtype":1,"ipinyouid":"D89E8S5bwWz","
useragent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)","ip":"61.138.253.*","regionid":374,"cityid":375,"adexchange":1,"domain":"449a7568331085d43
d5867de26ce1ee1","url":"5ecba5b62bafd3428cdc1398b40cf88f","anonymousurl":"null","adslotid":null,"adslotwidth":300,"adslotheight":250,"adslotvisibility":"Na","adslotformat":"Na","adslotfloorprice":0,"creativeid":
"10722","biddingprice":294,"payingprice":135,"landingpageurl":"null","advertiserid":2821,"userprofileids":[10006,10110,10063]}                                                                                     
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:565)                                                                                                                                
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:83)                                                                                                                  
        ... 17 more                                                                                                                                                                                                
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text hive.homework3.UserAgentDetector.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)  on object hive.homewor
k3.UserAgentDetector@1b340ab of class hive.homework3.UserAgentDetector with arguments {Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2):org.apache.hadoo
p.io.Text} of size 1                                                                                                                                                                                               
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1019)                                                                                                                      
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)                                                                                                              
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)                                                                                            
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)                                                                                                                    
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)                                                                                                                    
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:81)                                                                                                                           
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841)                                                                                                                                      
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:133)                                                                                                                    
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:170)                                                                                                                       
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:555)                                                                                                                                
        ... 18 more                                                                                                                                                                                                
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                                                                                                             
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                                                                                             
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                                                                                           
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                                                                   
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)                                                                                                                                                        
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:995)                                                                                                                       
        ... 27 more                                                                                                                                                                                                
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: eu/bitwalker/useragentutils/UserAgent                                                                                                                                   
        at hive.homework3.UserAgentDetector.formatter(UserAgentDetector.java:30)                                                                                                                                   
        at hive.homework3.UserAgentDetector.evaluate(UserAgentDetector.java:22)                                                                                                                                    
        ... 32 more                                                                                                                                                                                                
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.bitwalker.useragentutils.UserAgent                                                                                                                                 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)                                                                                                                                              
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                                                                                                                                                   
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)                                                                                                                                           
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                                                                                                                                                   
        ... 34 more                                                                                                                                                                                                
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:21, Vertex vertex_1501829365845_0009_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. fa
iledVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

from these as I understand that most important thing is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.bitwalker.useragentutils.UserAgent                                                                                                                                 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)                                                                                                                                              
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                                                                                                                                                   
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)                                                                                                                                           
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                                                                                                                                                   
        ... 34 more
```

this external lib I use in my maven project.

This is UDF creation and by the way in local works everything fine and test are passed. But in the Hive it doesnt work. I suppose that this lib which I use has problems but is it possible if I in local works fine?

```
import eu.bitwalker.useragentutils.UserAgent;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;


@Description(
        name = "agentdetector",
        value = "_FUNC_(str) - detects a user-agent of user",
        extended = "Example:\n" +
                " > SELECT agent(line) FROM test ipy; \n"
)
public class UserAgentDetector extends UDF {

    public Text evaluate(Text text) {
        Text value = new Text("");
        if (text != null) {
            value.set(formatter(text));
            return value;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Text formatter(Text text) {
        UserAgent userAgent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(text.toString());
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Browser : ").append(userAgent.getBrowser().getName()).append("\n");
        text.set(builder.toString());
        return text;
    }
```

And the dependency for maven is:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem just add plugin in you pom.xml

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>{pathToMainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and run assembly:assembly in plugins of maven.